# About derivative of the inverse function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I think I misunderstand something about derivative of the inverse function. Say we are transforming from (x,y) to (r, $\theta$), this requires calculating $\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}$.

$$x=rcos \theta$$
$$y=rsin\theta$$

Therefore:
$$\frac{\partial x}{\partial r} = cos\theta$$
And because of derivative of the inverse we have: $$dx/dy = \frac{1}{dy/dx}$$

, however $\frac{\partial r}{\partial x} \neq 1/cos\theta$. It is actually equal to $\frac{\partial r}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial \sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{\partial x} = cos\theta$.

I am not sure where I am going astray, please help if you understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What works when you have more than one variable is that the derivative *matrix* of the inverse mapping is the inverse of the *matrix* of the original mapping. So here you want the Jacobian matrix of $(x,y)$ with respect to $(r,\theta)$:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial (x,y)}{\partial (r,\theta)} &= \begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial x}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta} \\ \frac{\partial y}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta} \end{bmatrix}
\\ &=\begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta & -r\sin\theta \\
\sin\theta & r\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
Then we'll have
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial (r,\theta)}{\partial (x,y)} &= \begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial r}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial r}{\partial y} \\ \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial y} \end{bmatrix}
\\ &=\begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta & -r\sin\theta \\
\sin\theta & r\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}^{-1}  = \begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta & \sin\theta \\ -(\sin\theta)/r & (\cos\theta)/r\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
You can verify the final result by taking partial derivatives of $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and $\theta = \arctan(y/x)$ (up to a constant).

To elaborate slightly, when you try to apply the single-variable rule $dx/dy = \dfrac1{dy/dx}$ when you have more than one variable, you have to consider what partial derivative means. If you take $\partial r/\partial x$, you are computing the rate of change of $r$ as you vary $x$ *with $y$ fixed*. When you compute $\partial x/\partial r$ you are computing the rate of change of $x$ as your vary $r$ *with $\theta$ fixed*. What if you tried to compute the derivative of $x$ with respect to $r$ *fixing $y$* instead? This means that we are keeping $r\sin\theta$ constant, say $r\sin\theta=c$, so, assuming we have $0<\theta<\pi/2$ for concreteness, that will mean that $x=r\cos\theta=r\sqrt{1-(c/r)^2}$. I'll leave you to check that $\dfrac{dx}{dr} = \dfrac 1{\sqrt{1-(c/r)^2}} = \dfrac xr = \dfrac1{\partial r/\partial x}$, as you'd hoped.

By the way, physical chemists (and others) often use the notation $\left(\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial r}\right)_y$ to indicate explicitly what variables are being held constant. Now you can appreciate why.